Are faster or heavier objects in motion difficult to slow down due to kinetic energy or inertia?
I know that faster objects with more mass have a greater kinetic energy than slower objects with less mass. Does the kinetic energy or the inertia play a greater role in how difficult it is to stop these object, because objects with more mass have a greater tendency to remain in the same state of motion? Finally, does friction play a role as well, and can these three things be tied together? Thanks!
Edit: Here is a specific example to clarify. Consider a comparison of bullets from the two rifles.



Bullet
Mass (m)
Velocity (v)
KE ($1/2mv^2$)
Momentum (mv)




A
0.02 kg
1,500 m/s
22,500 Joule
30 Kg m/s


B
0.04 kg
1,000 m/s
20,000 Joule
40 Kg m/s



Bullets from rifle A have greater kinetic energy, but lower momentum than bullets from rifles B. Would a greater wall thickness (made of wood) be required to stop bullets from rifle A or B? Is momentum more significant than kinetic energy as far as penetration is concerned?

This question makes a lot of mistakes mixing things up, showing a lot of confusion. It is not correct to say that "Is more force required to absorb this energy"; they are not comparable this way. The rest mass of an object is a highly locked up form of energy; Inertia tracks the total energy of an object, i.e. more energy = more inertia, where you have to include rest mass energy. When people compare things, they keep as much of stuff the same as they can. Comparing "faster + more mass" with "slower and less mass" gives you something expected, but not very informative.

I didn't exactly know how to word my question and just started introductory physics last year, so I'm a little unclear.

That is ok, but you need to think about how to write your question, and then we can answer them.

What would you say happens to the energy instead of being absorbed?

That is not the part that is wrong. If you want to stop something, you have to take away its kinetic energy. If it has more of that, then you have to take away more kinetic energy. The problem is that it is not directly comparable to forces. For the same kinetic energy, you can use a large force over a short distance, or small force over a large distance, to take all of those kinetic energy away. You don't talk about "more force". That is just wrong.

Here's a simple example scenario to think about. We have 3 steel balls. Ball A has mass 100g & hits you at 1 m/s. Ball B has mass 1g & hits you at 100 m/s, so B has the same momentum as A. Ball C has mass 1g & hits you at 10 m/s, so C has the same KE as A. Which is worse, B or C? ;)

why would you pick a case with both momentum and energy different? In science, it's good to only change one variable at a time in a multivariate situation.

@JEB It is not just in science. In the humanities they have ceteris paribus too. When we are blessed with the ability to vary things independently and combine the results to make a comprehensive understanding, we do do that. If only there aren't complicated relationships breaking this method. The OP is just so confused that he did not remember to work things out this way.

I think it is also high time to note that, OP, you have spent the past 2 months on this site asking many questions around this topic. If you are good with mathematics, you can derive the answers to all of these things yourself. It will be vastly superior to asking a lot of open ended questions that people have to handwave answers to you.

@user386598 Does my edit and example reflect the gist of what you wanted to ask? I have to make sure my edit does not change your intention.

I am decent in mathematics and could likely solve this but one: I do not know nor understand all the formulas and two: I ask more conceptual questions to understand the science, not just the mathematical component.

To answer your question KDP, this mostly gets the gist of my question, but I was thinking about the amount of applied force necessary to stop a moving object.

Maybe I have the concept wrong, I don't really know.

@user386598 I have extended my answer to try and address your comment.

Fortunately, I answered it by considering only physics concepts: momentum, energy, impulse and work. I would include a picture if could, but the area of a triangle is $\frac 1 2$ base $\times$ height, so draw your own as you follow along.

@JEB To calculate impulse you need to know the time interval of the impact. Is this time interval the same for both types of bullets and if you think it is can you prove it? I am not aware of any published formula for the time interval of an impact. Are you?

@KDP \frac$ (v /$ impact-time$)^2 \approx $ penetration depth. That's why I replaced the vague bullet/impact with rocket/thrusters in my answer.

FWIW, 20 & 40 gram bullets are extremely heavy for rifle rounds. Usually you're looking in the 9 to 15 grams range, depending on the cartridge chosen.

The details of exactly what happens when a projectile enters a target material are reasonably complicated. There are obviously friction forces and compression forces involved. Friction is proportional to normal forces. As the bullet travels deeper into the target material, some of the material is displaced sideways and compressed, increasing the normal force as the bullet travels deeper into the material. The derivation of the formula for the penetration depth of a projectile is not trivial, but research over the years by the military indicates the penetration depth ($T$) is approximately proportional to $$T = kD\sqrt{\frac{W\times V^2}{D^3}},$$  where $k$ is an empirical constant, $W$ is the weight of the bullet, $V$ is the velocity of the bullet and $D$ is the diameter of the bullet. If we replace $W$ with the mass of the bullet and simplify a bit, we get:
$$T = k V \sqrt{\frac{M}{D}}.$$
This last equation tells us if both bullets have the same momentum on arrival at the target, the bullet with the higher velocity and lower mass will penetrate further (if the diameters are the same). The diameters of the bullets have not been given, but since bullet $\text{B}$ has a greater mass than bullet $\text{A}$, it is reasonable to assume that bullet $\text{B}$ has a greater diameter. I will use a value of $0.01 \ \text{m}$ for bullet $\text{A}$ and $0.012 \ \text{m}$ for bullet $\text{B}$ as hopefully reasonable estimates.
For bullet $\text{A}$ we get: $$T = k \times 1500 \sqrt{\frac{0.02}{0.01}} \approx 2121 k. $$
For bullet $\text{B}$ we get: $$T = k \times 1000 \sqrt{\frac{0.04}{0.012}} \approx 1825 k.$$
Since kinetic energy ($E_k$) is equal to $1/2 \, MV^2$ we can substitute $2E_k/V^2$ for $M$ in the equation for penetration depth and get: $$T = k \sqrt{\frac{2E_k}{D}},$$
which makes the importance of kinetic energy in penetration ability clear. This last equation tells us if the two bullets have the same kinetic energy as each other on arrival at the target, they will penetrate the same amount, even if they have different masses and velocities.
Although we do not know the value for the $k$ constant, it is the same for both bullets, so bullet $\text{A}$, which has greater kinetic energy, requires thicker armour to stop the bullet and bullet $\text{B}$ with the greater momentum has less penetration ability. Even if we assume bullet $\text{B}$ has the same slim diameter as bullet $\text{A}$, the result for $\text{B}$ is $2000 k$, which is still less than the penetration of bullet $\text{A}$.

this mostly gets the gist of my question, but I was thinking about the
amount of applied force necessary to stop a moving object. –
user386598

You cannot stop a bullet instantly unless it hits an object with infinite mass. You either have to stop a bullet over a given distance or over a given time. If you stop it over a given time, then force, then you are talking about the power required to stop a bullet. If you are talking about the force over a given distance, then you are talking about work or energy required to stop a bullet. It does not make sense to ask about the force required to stop a bullet without giving it context.
Work, which is a form of energy, can be defined as force $\times$ distance over which the force acts. We have calculated the distance the bullet travels inside the target material as $2121 k$, and the kinetic energy absorbed is the original $\text{KE}$ of the bullet, which is $45,000 \ \text{Joules}$. The average force acting on the bullet $\text{A}$ as it is stopped is $$\frac{45000}{2121 k} \approx 10.6 k^{-1} \ \text{Newtons}.$$ The average force acting on the bullet B as it is stopped is $$\frac{20000}{1825 k} \approx 10.95 k^{-1} \ \text{Newtons}.$$ In this sense, bullet $\text{B}$ with greater momentum requires greater force to stop it.
Let's consider the case where the target victim with mass $m_{1}$ is wearing a bulletproof vest, and the bullet is trapped in the material of the vest, so we have an inelastic collision. From that link, the final velocity of the victim after the impact is:
$$v_1 = \frac{m_2 u_2}{m_1+m_2},$$
where $m_2$ is the mass of the bullet, $u_2$ is the velocity of the bullet before impact and $m_1$ is the mass of the victim.
Assuming the victim has a mass of $80 \ \text{kg}$, the velocity of the victim after being hit by bullet $\text{A}$ is:
$$v_A = \frac{0.02 \times 1500}{80+0.02} \approx 0.37 \ \text{m/s}.$$
The velocity of the victim after being hit by bullet $\text{B}$ is:
$$v_B = \frac{0.04 \times 1000}{80+0.04} \approx 0.49 \ \text{m/s}.$$
Bullet $\text{B}$ results in the target being knocked back faster. Since momentum is velocity times mass and the mass of the target is $80 \ \text{kg}$ in both cases, bullet $\text{B}$ imparts more momentum to the target. This suggests that the bullet with the greater momentum imparts the greater momentum to the target (which is not surprising).
===============================================
All the above assumes the kinetic energy when the bullet hits the target is the same as when the bullet leaves the gun, but in reality, air resistance has a significant effect.
Wikipedia gives the velocity of the bullet as a function of time:
$$ v(t) = \frac{1}{\dfrac{1}{v_0} + \dfrac{2M}{cp \, \pi (D/2)^2} t},$$
where $v_0$ is the muzzle velocity as the bullet leaves the gun, $c$ is the drag coefficient of the air on the bullet, which takes the shape of the bullet into account, and $p$ is the density of the air. Air has a density of about $1 \ \text{kg/m}^3$, and for a bullet, an average coefficient of drag is around $0.5$. Assuming these values for both bullets, the equation can be written as $$ v(t) = \frac{1}{\dfrac{1}{v_0} + \dfrac{16M}{\pi D^2} t}.$$
This can be converted to kinetic energy as a function of time after the bullet leaves the gun: $$ E_k(t) = \frac{1}{2} M \left(\frac{1}{\dfrac{1}{v_0} + \dfrac{16M}{\pi D^2} t}\right)^2.$$
Plotting the kinetic energy of the two bullets against time after leaving the gun gives the graph below:

The interesting observation is that bullet $\color{blue}{\text{A}}$ (blue) with high initial kinetic energy rapidly slows down when air drag is taken into account. This is partly due to the fact that air drag is proportional to velocity squared, so the high-velocity bullet experiences more drag. For targets over about $400 \ \text{m}$ away, bullet $\color{orange}{\text{B}}$ (orange) retains its velocity better and, as a result, arrives at the target with higher kinetic energy and, therefore, the better penetrating ability for long-range shots. This suggests the high-momentum bullet does indeed sustain its velocity better than the "high kinetic energy bullet".

A less rigorous but maybe more intuitive way to think about it is this.  If colliding bodies hit each other and one or both bounce off the other, then momentum tells you more than energy.  If the colliding bodies end up being brought to rest quickly, as with a bullet penetrating a stationary object like a wall, then the energy content of the bullet is the more pertinent quantity.  Of course, they are both related mathematically.  But the energy in the bullet corresponds more closely with the material damage.  Because all that energy has to go somewhere.

...W is the might of the bullet... the what now? Also, rifle cartridges (6.5 CM, 308 Win, 270 Win, ...) are usually in the 7-9 mm range for diameters

@KyleKanos That was a typo. It should have said "W is the weight of the bullet". I used a diameter of 10 mm for bullet A. Not totally unrealistic.

10 mm is hand gun ammo sized, not rifle sized & 12 mm doesn't exist. Rifle cartridges are narrower & longer than hand gun rounds due to barrel lengths & associated pressures of the combustion. In fact, you can have the same exact rifle cartridge in many different weights (usually measured in grains which is about 1 grain : ~14 grams); the common 5.56 mm NATO round is usually found in 55 grain weights but can be found in 40 gr, 60 gr, 62 gr & 70 gr (among others). So the notion that "larger mass = larger bullet" is not strictly true (but would be if you're comparing different caliber rounds).

@KyleKanos Thanks for the real life info on munitions. I have added a bit to my answer which takes air drag into account, that you might be interested in. Air drag completely changes the conclusions.

According to your given first formula penetration depth $\large T \propto \sqrt{m} v$. So it's not directly linked to momentum, because $T$ dependance on bullet mass is not linear. Also it's not directly linked to bullet kinetic energy, because $T$ dependance on bullet speed is linear, while kinetic energy dependance - quadratic. It's only clear that penetration favors speed over mass, but does not follow kinetic energy tendencies.

@AgniusVasiliauskas  $KE = 1/2mv^2 \rightarrow m= 2KE/v^2$. Substitute this expression for m into $ \large T \propto \sqrt{m} v$ and you get \large $T \propto (2KE)^{1/2}$

In this case substituting doesn't mean anything,- I could substitute $m=p/v$ and get $T \propto \sqrt{pv}$, so ? Square root tells that linear increase of bullet kinetic energy does not reflect back as a linear increase of penetration depth. So, not the kinetic energy is the main player here, but bullet speed, because $T(v)$ dependence is linear.

@AgniusVasiliauskas The question was will the bullet with more kinetic energy penetrate deeper than the bullet with more momentum the answer is the former. However, you right that the bullet velocity  is the "main player".  The expression $T \propto \sqrt{pv}$ you obtained with the M=p/v substitution is not so helpful as it does not isolate the momentum from the velocity. The expression $T \propto \sqrt{KE}$ agrees with your observation that  $T \propto v$ because $KE \propto v^2$.

For me it's not so clear as to you (your main conclusion), because first as you've said momentum is not isolated from velocity (or mass), depending how you substitute momentum expression, so it's hard to evaluate momentum effect. Second,- if we look this way that doubling $KE$ makes $T$ bigger by $\sqrt{2}$ factor,- same goes as well by doubling bullet mass (which also is part of momentum). So to me it feels that both parameters are "on par". p.s. for mass doubling evaluate $\sqrt {p^{~2}/m}.$

@AgniusVasiliauskas If we agree more velocity is better when designing a bullet or rifle, the question is what are we trading velocity for? Does gaining velocity mean sacrificing  mass? I don't see any particular reason momentum should be a constraining parameter.  Cost is probably a more realistic design parameter. More mass costs more. More propellant costs more. A given quantity of propellant has a given energy which means all bullets fired with a given propellant will have the same kinetic energy (assuming same rifle barrel length).....

.....  This leaves us with a choice of mass. Less mass will mean more velocity for a given kinetic energy or propellant quantity. This should give us more penetration power. However if you read the last part of my answer, you will see that higher momentum means a bullet sustains it velocity (and therefore penetration power) over long distances). So the mass::velocity tradeoff will have to take intended range into account.

The answer depends on your definition of "difficult" when modifying "slowing down".
You are framing this question in terms of mass ($m_A, m_B$) and velocity ($v_A, v_B$), but your table has:
$$ m_A \ne m_B $$
$$ v_A \ne v_B $$
in a configuration such that:
$$ p_A \ne p_B $$
$$ E_A \ne E_B $$
where:
$$p_j = m_j v_j $$
$$E_j = \frac 1 2 m_j v_j^2 $$
are the standard momentum and kinetic energy, respectively.
It makes it difficult to compare, since all variables are different.
I think it's better to frame the problem in terms of mass and momentum or mass and kinetic energy with the condition:
$$ E = \frac{p^2}{2m}$$
so you immediately see that at fixed momentum, mass reduces kinetic energy, or at fixed energy:
$$ p = \sqrt{2mE} $$
mass and energy have equal weight in determining momentum.
Now if you have two projectiles with:
$$ m_B = 2m_A $$
and equal momenta, then:
$$ E_B = E_A / \sqrt 2 $$
and it takes more work to stop $A$ than $B$.
However, suppose you are doing that work with a thruster (thrust = $F$). Then you need to consider impulse (force $\times$ time):
$$ I = \int_0^t F(t')dt' = Ft $$
and use force as rate of change of momentum:
$$ F = \frac{dP}{dt} $$
Thus you need to fire the thrusters for times:
$$ t_A = \frac{p_A} F = \frac{p_B} F = t_B $$
which are equal.
The same amount of propellant is required and they are equally easy/difficult to stop.
The momentum is a function of time is:
$$ p_i(t)=p\ \ \ t \lt 0$$
$$ p_i(t)=0-Ft\ \ \ 0 \le t \le t_i$$
$$ p_i(t)=0\ \ \ t \gt t_i$$
from which we can calculate the work done:
$$ W_i = \int_{x=0}^{x_{final}} F(x')dx' $$
which I don't want to deal with--position, we don't have $x_{final}$.
Instead, consider the power:
$$ P(t) = \frac{dW}{dt}$$
so that:
$$ W_i = \int_{t'=0}^t P_i(t')dt'$$
where $P_i$ is the power input from thrust:
$$ P_i(t) = Fv_i(t) = \frac F{m_i} p_i(t) $$
so that the work is:
$$ W_i = \frac F{m_i}\int_{t'=0}^{t_i} (p_i-Ft')dt'$$
$$ W_i = \frac F{m_i}(p_it'-\frac 1 2 Ft'^2)|_{t'=0}^{t_i}$$
$$ W_i = \frac F{m_i}(p_it_i-\frac 1 2 Ft_i^2) $$
$$ W_i = \frac {Ft_i}{m_i}(p_i-\frac 1 2 Ft_i) $$
$$ W_i = \frac {Ft_i}{m_i}(p_i-\frac 1 2 p_i) $$
$$ W_i = \frac {Ft_i}{2m_i}p_i $$
$$ W_i = \frac {p_i}{2m_i}p_i $$
$$ W_i = \frac{p_i^2}{2m_i} = E_i $$
as expected. It takes more work to stop the smaller mass at equal momentum.
Note that by minimizing the use of velocity profiles, I did not need to consider positions $x_i(t)$, which is doable, but less clear imho.
Edit: Let me summarize. Use momentum and (kinetic) energy as independent variables, and remember:

Force is the time rate of change of momentum: $F=dp/dt$.

Force is the change of energy with respect to distance: $F=dE/dx$.


The above are connected by:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = p/m$

$\frac{dE}{dp} = p/m$


Edit per @Neil Libertine:
OK, in case you didn't notice, I reject the question as malformed, as it has zero pedagogical value, as explained above. Moreover, picking two cases with energy and momenta that are only 30% different is hardly going to allow intuition to kick in.
One thing that helps with kinematic intuition is to compare extreme cases. So instead of two bullets with almost the same mass fired out of almost the same platform, I will pick:
A uranium atom:
$$ m_A = 400\,{\rm yg} $$
and a mod'd cybertruck:
$$ m_B = 3\,{\rm Mg} $$
with momentum $p=30\,{\rm kg\cdot m/s^2}$. They have energies:
$$ E_A \approx \gamma m_Ac^2 \approx pc = 9\,{\rm GJ} $$
(moving at $v_A\approx c - \frac c {2\gamma^2} = c(1-8\times 10^{-36})$)
$$ E_B = 150\,{\rm mJ} $$
moving at $v_B=p/m_B = 1\,{\rm cm/s}$.
Which one will penetrate deeper in a collision with a tree?

Your conclusion is that more energy is required to stop smaller mass with same momentum is incorrect because speed is not sole contributor for momentum and using energy is flawed. Energy is not conserved thing in these situations. What is your opinion about given question, which bullet needs more stuff to stop or difficult to stop.

Just because Einstein used energy term for resisting speed on applying force make it legible term for inertia, energy is not inertia. Yes, bullet B needs more thick wall to stop it and thus more momentum is important when matter is treated as particle or lumped mass.
